# translate kbps video stream to video resolution

Tags: video-streaming, audio-streaming

In the NFL game pass site they offer a video stream of the games upto 3000 kbps.
I want to know to what resolution this translates to 
(hd, sd, 1080p, 720p)
and how many frame per sec.
Can I figure this out from their the 3000kbps pace?
Thanks.

BTW : 
I have seen it here 
https://gamepass.nfl.com/nflgp/secure/packages?ttv=1&ttp=3&ccfeatures=true

Comment: Short answer: No

Comment: Actually I thought it was the answer but it seemed strange though that they happily advertise the quality with data that doesn't actually say anything. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [bitrate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitrate#Multimedia) used cannot be "translated" to resolution or the like, as it usually is dynamic for best results. To give you a visual example: a 5s video with many colors and fast moving elements (think of sports) needs quite a lot of information to be encoded, especially for HD. But if the screen is completely and constantly blank, all you need is to say "all pixels black for 5s", regardless of the resolution. Same for sound (complete silence for 5s). Something similar is done with the codecs used, to save bandwidth.

So all you can do is hope for a good guess if you know about the length of that video...

Comment: Very true, plus: Bitrate not only depends on the complexity of the source material and on the resolution, but also on the desired end result. Most codecs have "quality" parameters, and different parameters will produce different output sizes even for identical source material.